# Publishing ACCDE Version Drops All Macros

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access Database Frontend that contains a large body of macros, queries, and custom VBA code. This frontend connects through linked tables to our backend access database. In order to allow multiple users to use the database we publish an ACCDE version. For some reason macros are not being included in this published version. Normally you can't see the code but the module names are always listed. This is completely blank, no macros, no vba, and auto exec fails to call a few custom functions as well. VBA code is simply not included.

I've tried:

- Compiling the VBA Code -> Works without errors and publishing still doesn't include macros
- Saving my frontend as a new file and then publishing
- Compact and Repair
- Different OS/Different Version of Access/Different Computer

I'm not seeing any errors when publishing, all my references are there, there's no reason for this to be failing as far as I can tell. The only indication that this happened is opening the ACCDE version and getting an error about auto_exec being unable to locate my function.

Ideally I'd like to not have to restore a version and lose changes that I've made.

Comment: I'm assuming you have your database opening a form when the user opens the database file (accde). If so, move your code from the auto_exec to the Form_Load event on the form and see if this solves the issue.

there might also be a change in the function that the Auto_Exec is unable to locate.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not even that auto exec can't locate it, if I hit F11 the module names are all gone. They're just missing.

Comment: Then the next question is, did you hit your 2 Gb limit? If so and this isn't a split database, Access will do the first thing necessary in order to preserve your data, and that's dump all your codes.

Comment: Nope, it's a split with a backend and frontend. The file size is only about 10MB

Comment: might try checking your macro builder instead of VBA. They might be built as macros